# Django > xhtml2pdf > Getting it to work?

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I'm having problems understanding how I should install xhtml2pdf. I have followed the instructions at [Chris Glass's](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf/) site and have a virtual environment setup and have run unit tests. When I insert the following at the top of my `views.py` file:

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO
import cgi
import os
```

I get an error saying `No module named ho.pisa` *(which I expected)*. How do I get django or even the python command line import this module *(because I have tried importing the module in the command line with the same level of success)*.

**EDIT**

Why do I need a virtual enviroment. Can't I just install `xhtml2pdf` as a package and import it normally or will I break some Django/python thing?

**EDIT**

I have also run django from inside the xhtml2pdf virtual enviroment > `(xhtml2pdfenv)person@person-laptop:~/Software/django$ ./manage.py runserver` and still it refuses to import `xhtm2pdf`

Comment: You need to make sure you set your environment first before you use django in virtualenv.

source django-env/bin/activate

Comment: I did that. I followed the install instructions for xhtml2pdf to the letter

Comment: Just to clarify. I have xhtml2pdf in a virtual enviroment NOT django. Django just runs normally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried installing xhtml2pdf using pip, not the package.

The `pisa` module was in `xhtml2pdf`, not `ho`

```
>>> import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
```

Comment: just to add a little more detail, when I did **pip install pisa** it installed in ho. When I did **pip install xhtml2pdf** it installed in the xhtml2pdf directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [virtualenv and additional libraries for django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646908/virtualenv-and-additional-libraries-for-django) or install from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa/

Answer (score 0):

Right. I got it to work by doing the following **after step 5** of the **development enviroment** at Chris Glass's site:

```
$ python setup.py install
# navigate to you django project
$ cd ../django
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

The import line `from xhtml2pdf import pisa` in `views.py` does not raise any errors any more

Answer (score 0):

You can install pisa by following line:

```
easy_install pisa
```